# Laravel/MYSQL created_at and updated_at are applying different timezones

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an app that is using

```
'timezone' =>'UTC'
```

in the database settings.  This is working for all the created_at fields, however the updated_at fields are still in the wrong timezone

How do I get MYSQL to apply the correct timezone to the updated_at field??

These are my DB settings

```
'default' => 'main_db',
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
'connections' => [
    'main_db' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'timezone' => env('DB_TIMEZONE')
```

with env('DB_TIMEZONE') being 'UTC'

Comment: it should work for both,,could you be more specific please?

Comment: Check your controllers. You might have overloaded some default functionality.

Answer (score 2):

We go to the file `config/app.php` and look for this entry:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

As you can see, **UTC** is a default value for Laravel. So you can easily change it here to, for example, **Europe/London** or **America/Los_Angeles** - See full list [PHP Supported Timezones](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp)

If you change this setting, unfortunately old entries won’t be changed automatically, but new ones will be saved with **created_at, updated_at** and similar fields in your specified timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem I just put my country zone and it worked for me

```
'timezone' =>'America/Vancouver'
```

Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to check DB as there datatypes are similar or not and default also check if you have applied cuurent timestamp as default then

check DB.